# T-SQL, Picking lowest date per row where X,X and X happen

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-function

I've got an interesting problem, I created a view in SQL to aggregate some data on Orders so if an item is out of stock or we can't fill it, we can see why and see when the next time we'll get a shipment of that part in and how much. This would ive us a decent idea of when it'll be next available for an order. Unfortunately I'm getting Orders listed multiple times with ALL future part purchase dates so the data is roughly displayed as such:

```
    Order#  Part  OrderQty  AvailableQty PartPurchaseDate PurchaseQty
    111       B     25        0           1/1/2016         15
    111       B     25        0           2/1/2016         50
    112       C     500       0           1/3/2016         400
    113       B     11        0           1/1/2016         15
    113       B     11        0           2/1/2016         50
```

---

Ok so first I'll apologize or the confusing format. Part of this project is figuring out how to format my questions to lead to the right answer. To clarify the above data is what I'm currently getting, which is just listing all possibilities with no real logic involved. Ignore that example, it seems that made it more confusing. Lets assume 3 tables because I think that will be easier. You have OrdDetail:

```
    Order#    Part   OrderQty
    111       B      25
    112       C      500
    113       B      11
```

PartQuantity (Which is really lots of quantity data summing to get what we deem as "Available") The reason they're all 0 was for simplicity. In this case there are none of X part in the warehouse right now that we can use, and we won't have any until a certain date. At which point other smaller orders may be filled first if we did have an available quantity, so for this we're just trying to see where the PO Quantity is estimated to fill the entire order. Its not perfect, and often we do fill orders in the order they are received but this is just for a rough ETA, so assumptions like this are acceptable. If we did have only a partial fill from Available we'll likely have either Reserved parts or shipped a partial order so that quantity would be Unavailable or the OrderQty would have been updated:

```
   Part       AvailableQTY
   B          0
   C          0
```

And then PurchaseOrder:

```
    Part    PartPurchaseDate    PurchaseQty
    B       1/1/2016            15
    C       1/3/2016            400
    B       2/1/2016            50
```

PartPurchaseDate being the date I expect those parts to be received, so our Available would go from 0 to 15 of Part B on 1/1/2016. Now since that doesn't fill the order #111 completely then it wouldn't receive an ETA, but #113 could be filled and the ETA for that would be 1/1/2016. Below is the rough output I'd like to receive after I join OrdDetail to PartQuantity and then grab the nearest date off the PO table that an entire order can be filled. Order #112 doesn't show up, which is fine, we just don't have an ETA for that Order (at which point the sales rep calls purchasing to complain and it stops being my problem).

```
    Order#  Part  OrderQty  AvailableQty PartPurchaseDate PurchaseQty
    111       B     25        0           2/1/2016        50
    113       B     11        0           1/1/2016        15
```

I understand this isn't complete with all data one might want to grab, and you guys may have questions as to why do it this way. This isn't something I'm copy/pasting. Just trying to figure out how something might work, so I'm giving you guys 10,000 ft information for a 10,000 ft answer. I apologize for the delay in getting back, holidays are my excuse.

Comment: I'm not following - where do you see in your table that order 113 had 20 available?  The `AvailableQty` for everything is 0.

Comment: Your view clearly does not have enough information (without a lot of work) to get any date for Order 111.  The purchase qty is less than the order qty, so according to the row, it is simply unavailable.  I would suggest that you modify this question or ask another with the orders and future product orders to address your question.

Comment: Try joining the table to itself so you can get a running sum.

Comment: This would be a lot easier with just gave us the base tables rather than the view you have  butchered up

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got seems to work, found the minimum part purchase date for each order put that value with the order it belonged to into a # table then joined it to the maintable to get only the information you needed.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (ordernum varchar(5), part varchar(2), orderqty int, availableqty int, partpurchasedate date, purchaseqty int)

INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT '113', 'B', 11, 0, '2016/2/1', 50 -- edited this line to add the other values

--- This is the part the partains to your question

SELECT OrderNum, MIN(partpurchasedate) minppd -- find min partpurchasedate for each order
into #tmp2 -- put it into a #table 
from #tmp 
where purchaseqty > orderqty -- make sure the purchase qty is > or orderqty
group by ordernum

SELECT a.* 
FROM #tmp a 
JOIN #tmp2 b on a.ordernum = b.ordernum -- join the tables together on their order number
where a.partpurchasedate = minppd -- only show orders whose date match the ppd we found earlier
```

Results are what you specified you wanted I hope this helps.

Comment: Thats a neat approach! That's more or less what I started out trying to do. I'm learning that may not be the BEST way for me to solve this issue but that's definitely what I asked for. Thanks for the input

Comment: @BWoods No problem, may I ask why?

Comment: The view I started with won't give me what i want with the flexibility I need, so I broke it down again (like the above edit). The project is a spring board for other projects spun off this ETA data, and since Im still learning this technology im still learning what it is I SHOULD be asking/looking for. I like this approach of making "saves" then manipulating them. But what I think I'm hoping for is a function that accepts multiple options as inputs then takes the dates/quantities into account to figure an ETA out. But maybe I'm just making it hard on myself by trying to catch all wants in one

Answer (score 0):

This code piece seems to meet your requirments. It uses ROW_NUMBER() to create a ranking for based on the service date for each Order that a greater PurchaseQty then Order Qty and then displays the earliest row associated with that rank.

```
SELECT
    c.[ORDER]
,   c.Part
,   c.OrderQty
,   c.AvailableQty
,   c.PartPurchaseDate
,   c.PurchaseQty
FROM
(
    SELECT
        b.[ORDER]
    ,   b.Part
    ,   b.OrderQty
    ,   b.AvailableQty
    ,   b.PartPurchaseDate
    ,   b.PurchaseQty
    ,   Order_Rank = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY b.[ORDER] ORDER BY b.PartPurchaseDate)
    FROM
        #ORDER b 
    WHERE
        b.PurchaseQty > b.OrderQTY -- Only concerned when Purchase quantity greater than order quantity
) c
WHERE
    c.Order_Rank = 1 -- Displays the earliest ranking 


ORDER   Part    OrderQty    AvailableQty    PartPurchaseDate    PurchaseQty
111     B       25          0               2016-02-01          50
113     B       11          0               2016-01-01          15
```

Comment: I don't think this credits for OrderQty < PurchaseQty

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this using an analytical function.

```
select
      orders.OrderId
    , orders.Part 
    , orders.OrderQty
    , orders.AvailableQty
    , case 
        when orders.PurchaseQty > orders.OrderQty then 
            min(orders.PartPurchaseDate) over (partition by orders.OrderId) 
        else orders.PartPurchaseDate 
    end as PartPurchaseDate
    , orders.PurchaseQty
from #Orders orders
```

Results

```
OrderId Part    OrderQty    AvailableQty    PartPurchaseDate    PurchaseQty
111     B       25          0               2016-01-01          15
111     B       25          0               2016-01-01          50
112     C       500         0               2016-01-03          400
113     B       11          0               2016-01-01          15
113     B       11          0               2016-01-01          50
```

background code

```
create table #Orders 
(
    OrderId int
    , Part varchar(1)
    , OrderQty int
    , AvailableQty int
    , PartPurchaseDate date
    , PurchaseQty int
)

insert into #Orders (

    OrderId
    , Part 
    , OrderQty
    , AvailableQty
    , PartPurchaseDate 
    , PurchaseQty
)
values
  (111,'B' , 25, 0 , '1/1/2016',15   )
, (111,'B' , 25, 0 , '2/1/2016',50   )
, (112,'C' , 500 , 0 , '1/3/2016',400)
, (113,'B' , 11, 0 , '1/1/2016',15   )
, (113,'B' , 11, 0 , '2/1/2016',50   )

select
      orders.OrderId
    , orders.Part 
    , orders.OrderQty
    , orders.AvailableQty
    , orders.min(orders.PartPurchaseDate) over (partition by orders.OrderId) as PartPurchaseDate
    , orders.PurchaseQty
from #Orders orders
```

P.S., Why is fulfillment data on the customer orders table?

Comment: I don't think this deal with cumulative or credit of and order the uses less than the PurchaseQty

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume what the real tables are
That view is not a good starting point

This just fills the order in order# but on a visual you can flop stuff around

```
with cte CumOrder as 
(  select O1.Part, O1.order#, O1.OrderQty, Sum(O2.OrderQty) as Cum
     from Order O1 
     join Order O2 
           on O2.Part = O1.Part 
          and O2.Order# >= O2.Order# 
    group by O1.Part, O1.order#, O1.OrderQty
)
,        CumSuplier as
(  select S1.Part, S1.Odate, S1.OrderQty, Sum(S2.OrderQty) as Cum
     from Supplier S1 
     join Supplier S2 
           on S2.Part = S1.Part 
          and S2.Odate >= S1.Odate 
    group by S1.Part, S1.Odate, S1.OrderQty 
)
select * from 
(  select CumOrder.Part, CumOrder.order#, CumOrder.OrderQty as [CumOrder.OrderQty], CumOrder.Cum as [CumOrder.Cum] 
        , CumSuplier.Odate as [CumSuplier.Odate]
        , CumSuplier.Cum as [CumSuplier.Cum] 
        , (CumSuplier.Cum - CumOrder.Cum) as Net 
        , rowNumber over (partition by CumOrder.Part, CumOrder.order# order by CumOrder.Odate) as rn
     from CumOrder  
     join CumSuplier 
            on CumSuplier.Part = CumOrder.Part
           and CumSuplier.Cum >= CumOrder.Cum 
)  ttt 
where rn = 1 
order by O1.Part, O1.order#
```